# Resizing image increases noise?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-resizing

I want to know that when we resize the image from 30x30 pixels image to 150x150 pixels image using Matlab. Does resizing adds extra noise in the image? Or vice versa case

Comment: Depends how you measure noise

Comment: If i am saying noise means not exact pixel values. Like resizing smaller image to large using interpolation parameter it will add extra pixel that might not be exact values of image.

Comment: Words are bad mathematical equations. You need to know *precisely* how you define noise. Amount of bad pixels? ovbiously a bigger image will have more pixels, thus more bad pixels. SNR? then likely the noise is similar or the same. High frequency noise? Interpolating will reduce the frequency of the noise thus reducing the higher band.

Comment: I want to show that same target can be captured using different number of pixels depends upon the specification of the sensor. If we resize the smaller image to match the size of higher pixel image the resized image will have more calculated pixels thus have more snr than actual higher Pixel image

Comment: SNR is a *ratio*, thus it should be irrelevant how many total pixels there are. In any case, this is not a programming question, but either hardware or basic concepts question

Comment: In your point of view, resizing the image increases the noise?

Comment: That’s correct its a basic concept question

Answer (score 2):

Resize down may increase SNR (if for example, each destination pixel is sum of 2x2 source pixels). Resize up increases blur, but does not suppose to decrease the SNR.

You can make a simple test:
Load a "clean image", create noisy image by adding random Gaussian noise, and measure the SNR.

Example:

```
I = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif')); %I is the "clean" image.
J = imnoise(I); %Add noise
N = J - I; %Noise image
r = snr(I, N);
```

Result: `r = 14.84`

Resize down:

```
I2 = imresize(I, 0.5);
J2 = imresize(J, 0.5);
N2 = J2 - I2;
r2 = snr(I2, N2);
```

Result: `r2 = 22.41` (SNR is improved by about factor of sqrt(2) - theoretical improvement).

Resize up:

```
I3 = imresize(I2, 2);
J3 = imresize(J2, 2);
N3 = J3 - I3;
r3 = snr(I3, N3);
```

Result: `r3 = 23.66` (SNR is a about the same)